# Looker Studio data formatting issue (making multiple columns become one dimension, and summarising int columns to create multiple metrics)

Tags: sql, visualization, looker-studio

I've encountered a problem trying to visualise data using Google's Looker Studio and would very much appreciate some help, explained below.

I'm pulling data from a database using SQL and want to visualise this in a pie chart, where I have data formatted like the one below making it easy to present as a pie chart:

| Year | Type | Class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | A | 1 |
| 2021 | B | 1 |
| 2022 | B | 1 |
| 2023 | C | 3 |

With the above formatting, I can e.g. easily set up a pie chart to visualise the Type distribution for year 2020-2023 (25% A, 50% B, 25% C) or Class distribution for years 2021-2023 (67% Class 1, 33% Class 3).

However, another table stores data a bit differently, like this:

| Year | Amount-A-of-Type | Amount-B-of-Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 22 | 15 |
| 2021 | 54 | 27 |
| 2022 | 11 | 61 |
| 2023 | 13 | 88 |

With the above format, I would like to use a pie chart to summarise the column values and visualise the distribution between Amount A and Amount B for selected years, e.g. 2021-2022 (A: 54+11=65, B: 27+61=88), making a distribution of 42% Amount A and 58% Amount B. So basically the Looker Studio **Dimension** should be "Type" and the  two Metrics should be A and B.

This **feels** like a seemingly simple task, but I just can't wrap my head around how to do it. Is this a matter of configuring Looker Studio in a certain way, or a smart SQL to create the prerequisites for the pie chart?  Would greatly appreciate some support in my thought process here.

Many thanks